# when running a script in python it asks for user input multiple times even though it is stateted in the script only once

Tags: python, python-3.x

so here is the thing i have

i have two script **script1.py** and **script2.py**

**script1.py** main idea is two gather the user's inputs via the input function, assining it to variables and calling the execution of **script2.py**. here is an example of **script1.py**:

```
a = input('enter value a - ')
b = input('enter value b - ')
c = input('enter value c - ')

with open('script2.py) as script2:
    exec(script2.read())
```

**script2.py** task is to import these input variables from **script1.py**, combine them into value and print it. the example of the code for **script2.py** is provided below.

```
from script1 import a, b, c

total_value = a + b + c

print(total_value)
```

whenever i run **script1.py** shown above it asks me to input value a, b, c two times in a row and then it prints the total_value two times as well.

here is the output of **script1.py**

```
enter value a - 1
enter value b - 2
enter value c - 3
enter value a - 1
enter value b - 2
enter value c - 3
123
123
```

i don't understand why **script1.py** is asking to provide extra input one more time when it was previously mentioned. is it because i'm calling the **script2.py** and it requires these values to operate?

anyway, how do i go about this and make it so it asks for input only one time and preferably prints the total_value only one time?

Comment: `script2` imports `script1` and `script1`is therefore executed again. Why do you use `exec` at all?

Comment: hmm, i see. i'm using exec to run script2.py. the idea for these two scripts is the following: script1.py collects all of the inputs and runs script2.py which does all of the calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen your code. In your code while running script1 it wants the input for 1st time, Then again while importing the a, b, c from script1, you were executing the code of script1.py that wants input again.
You can say its like a little loop that executes script1 in script2, and executes script2 in script1,

So we just need to wrap the input things in a function of python and then return the a, b, c values in function and import the function in script2 and store the values by running the function there. Also for stopping the loop we need wrap the line, what executes script2.py in if **name** == "**main**", so it doesn't runs twice

You can see example code below,

script1.py

```py
# script 1

def get_input():
    a = input('enter value a - ')
    b = input('enter value b - ')
    c = input('enter value c - ')
    return a, b, c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('script2.py') as script2:
        exec(script2.read())
```

Script2.py

```py
# script 2

from script1 import get_input

a, b, c = get_input()

total_value = a + b + c

print(total_value)
```

Comment: Maybe you should define the function as `def get_input(a, b, c)`. And after importing, you should call the function as `get_input(a, b, c)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of your problem that shows exactly which scope each line is executed in:

```py
print("entering __name__:", __name__)
a = input("enter value a - ")

from script1 import a

print(a)
print("exiting __name__:", __name__)
```

```
❯ python script1.py
entering __name__: __main__
enter value a - 8
entering __name__: script1
enter value a - 9
9
exiting __name__: script1
9
exiting __name__: __main__
```

More generally, this is due to how Python handles circular imports!

Answer (score 0):

1. while running script2.py, initially the first three lines are executed. So, it asks for input a,b,c
2. Now the third line is to open script2 and execute it. The first line if script2 (i.e) to import a, b, c from script1. To get a, b, c again it needs three input. Note: script2 doesn't know that the value of a, b, c has already been given. Because it is a separate file.

So. you have to follow any of these 2 methods:

```
#script1.py
a = input('enter value a - ')
b = input('enter value b - ')
c = input('enter value c - ')

#script2.py
from script import a, b, c

total_value = a + b + c

print(total_value)

#Execute script2.py
python3 script2.py
```

The second method is not much appreciated. If you are specific in running script1 to get the result you can follow this.

```
#script1

#declare a, b, c as global variables
global a, b, c
a = input('enter value a - ')
b = input('enter value b - ')
c = input('enter value c - ')

with open('script2.py', 'r') as script2:
    exec(script2.read())
    

#script2

global a, b, c

total_value = a + b + c

print(total_value)

#Run script1 to get result
python3 script1.py
```